# add popup on :after pseudo element with css

Tags: html, css, popup, pseudo-element

I'm interesting is there are a way to add a small popup box on `:after` pseudo element when I hover it? Is it possible to do it without HTML at all? I tried to search the web for it, but it seems that I always need some kind of `<span>` or `<div>` elements in markup to display popup text. Although I want to do it with pure CSS. Is there are some tricks for that?

```
button::after {
  content: "i";
  color: blue;
}

button:hover::after {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  // add css to display popup
}
```

Comment: we can't create elements in css. we can only create elements in HTML markup and in javascript through(document.createElement).css is used to style the elements that appear on the page

Comment: Is [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NgogPZ) what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Just for demo.

try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.block{display:none;padding:20px;}
button::after {
  content: "i";
  color: blue;
  height:
}
button:hover::after {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button:hover~.block{display:block !important;background-color:red !important;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="button"></button>
    <div class="block">Alert</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sure,** there is way to do, basically **:after** and **:before** pseudo needs always an elements to be before or after that element, but we can mix it with hover to do what you are looking for like below, run the code below to see how it's working for you:

```css
button {
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 32px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:after {
  content: 'x';
  font-size: 32px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

button:hover:after {
  display: block;
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">x</button>
```